# my server resultset is taking long time while looping through

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server-2012

I am facing performance issue with my sql server when I am trying to connect using a java application. sqljdbc4-4.0 is my driver version. Looks like this is the latest available for this.

The issue comes when I use the PreparedStatemnt with the set paramerter option and when looping trough the result set after a specific number of iterations the execution stops amost 5min and start iterating again. This stopping occuring on some fixed iterations.

This behavior occurs even for very simple query like below.

```
PreparedStatemnt ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
ps = con.prepareStatemnt("select id,name,phone from Table1 where name = ?");
ps.setString(1, "Raj");

rs = ps.executeQuery();   // OK here
int i=0;
while(rs.next()){            // hangs here
   System.out.println(i++);
}
```

However, it works fine if I do not set the parameter and concatenate the parameter to the query like this,

```
PreparedStatemnt ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
ps = con.prepareStatemnt("select id,name,phone from Table1 where name = 'Bob' ");

rs = ps.executeQuery();   // OK here
int i=0;
while(rs.next()){            // OK now
    System.out.println(i++);
}
```

when I use the query with no where condition it runs perfectly with no hanging.

This tell me that the issue comes when I use the set parameter option . I have tried to use the top rows to see whether the issue is with the large number of rows. But even when I set the top with 100. For these 100 rows itself the iterations stopped 2 times at 28th iteration and 66th iterations. I think on which iteration it hangs is depends on size of the number of columns.

can some one help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Syam.

Answer (score 0):

You have more, many more, Rajs than Bobs in your database.

It has nothing to do with whether you use `PreparedStatement` arguments or not.

Comment: I have tried the same with "Raj" in the second query itself. Even that case also it ran fast. I have even tried with the date range in the where condition such as select id,name,phone from Table1 where Date between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27'. The result is same, it is taking very long time at 28th and 66th.